# Связь JSF (PrimeFaces) Managed Bean и JS/Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Хочу сделать примерно следующее: есть меню, состоящие из существующих отделов; при нажатии на элемент меню отображается блок, содержащий элементы этого отдела; страница при этом не перезагружается.
*У меня почему не запоминается в бине выбранный отдел.*
Итак, само меню:

```
<h:form>
    <p:menu>
        <p:submenu label="Отделы" >
            <c:forEach var="dep" items="#{initIndex.deps}">
                <p:menuitem value="#{dep.name.toUpperCase()}" actionListener="#{initIndex.showElementsOfDep(dep)}" />
            </c:forEach>
        </p:submenu>
    </p:menu>
</h:form>
```

Бин InitIndex:

```
@ManagedBean    
@ViewScoped  
public class InitIndex implements Serializable {  
    /*отделы*/  
    private ArrayList<ProductDepart> deps = null;  
    /*текущий отдел*/  
    private ProductDepart curDep = null;  
    /*список товаров текущего отдела*/  
    private ArrayList<Product> curListProd = null;  

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        deps = new ConnectWithDB().getdeparts();
    }

    /*геттеры - сеттеры*/


    public void showElementsOfDep(ProductDepart dep) {
        deps.stream().filter((curDep1) -> (curDep1 == dep)).forEach((curDep1) -> {
            curDep = curDep1;
        }); 

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("showElementsOfDep();");
        System.out.println(curDep.getId() + " id CURDEP");
    }}
```

Метод JS showElementsOfDep() просто отображает нужный div:

```
function showElementsOfDep() {  
    $("#startWin").hide();  
    $("#goods_block").show();  

    return false;  
}
```

В консоли информация при выборе элемента меню отображается корректно, отображается нужный мне блок, но вот значение переменной не изменяется.
Пример этого блока:

```
<div id="goods_block">
    Товары из отдела #{initIndex.curDep.name.toUpperCase(locale)}   
</div>
```

Извините за корявое оформление вопроса, ещё не разобралась до конца как вставлять код :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы обновить средствами JSF нужно чтобы обновляемый блок страницы был бы JSF-компонентом, а не каким-то несчастным div-ом.
Потом надо указать какой или какие компоненты обновить. Если используете Primefaces, то у "командных" тегов есть атрибут `update`. В нем надо перечислить клиентские айдишники обновляемых компонентов. (В стоковых тегах JSF используется атрибут `rerender`)
Ваша страница JSF могла бы выглядеть так:

```
<h:form>
    <p:menu>
        <p:submenu label="Отделы" >
            <c:forEach var="dep" items="#{initIndex.deps}">
                <p:menuitem value="#{dep.name.toUpperCase()}"
                            actionListener="#{initIndex.showElementsOfDep(dep)}" 
                            update=":goods_block"
                            oncomplete="showElementsOfDep()"/>
            </c:forEach>
        </p:submenu>
    </p:menu>
</h:form>
...
<h:panelGroup id="goods_block" layout="block">
     Ништяки из отдела #{initIndex.curDep.name.toUpperCase(locale)}   
</h:panelGroup>
```

Заметьте, что вызов javascript-а часто тоже можно выполнить прямо на странице.
`h:panelGroup` выводит `span` или `div`, в зависимости от `layout-а`.

Кроме декларативного способа существуют и программные способы обновления.
В том же Primefaces это делается так:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("goods_block");
```

Отдельного внимания требуют айдишники JSF. Можно посмотреть в инструментах разработчика браузера какие они получаются, чтобы наверняка не ошибиться при передаче в javascript.
Кстати двоеточие в `:goods_block` - это не очепятка. Именно так их и надо указывать на страницах в подавляющем большинстве случаев. И отсутствие этого двоеточия в вызове метода тоже не опечатка.

А зачем @ManagedBean? Это же прошлый век. Из-за @ViewScoped? Но вроде уже есть ViewScoped для CDI. Ну это так. Сам-то не использую ни тот, ни другой. Может он ничуть не лучше старого.

Comment: я буквально 4-5 дней назад начала изучать JSF, поэтому, возможно, и использую что-то не по-современному. Спасибо вам большое за ответ, очень помогли :)